# Lvalue to rvalue conversion with integer pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, lvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

If I read [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) correctly:

> Lvalue to rvalue conversion
>
> **A glvalue of any non-function, non-array type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue of the same type**. [..]
>
> Unless encountered in unevaluated context (in an operand of sizeof, typeid, noexcept, or decltype), this conversion **effectively copy-constructs a temporary object of type T using the original glvalue as the constructor argument, and that temporary object is returned as a prvalue.**

Then why does this not work?

```
int* iptr = nullptr;
int*&& irr = iptr; // Cannot bind lvalue to rvalue reference
```

The type `int*` should have been implicitly converted to a prvalue of the same type via a temporary - thus binding to the rvalue reference without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard states that this is ill-formed explicitly; lvalue-to-rvalue conversion won't (shouldn't) be considered.

From [[dcl.init.ref]/5.4.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.4):

> if the reference is an rvalue reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> double d2 = 1.0;
> double&& rrd2 = d2;                 // error: initializer is lvalue of related type
> ```

Comment: I kinda hate C++ for this sort of things: exceptions and corner cases.

Comment: @Dean Well, the basic idea is clear; i.e. can't bind lvalues to rvalue-reference. So it might be better just don't consider too much, including why not applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in reference binding; they're also kinda corner cases. :)